# Magento 2.3 - Move billing address below shipping address in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, onepage-checkout, billing-address

I want to move the billing address form below the shipping address in the checkout, on the first page/step.

Therefore I created a custom module with the following LayoutProcessorPlugin.php.

But now the billing address field is displayed above the shipping address instead of below. And the default checkbox 'My billing and shipping address are the same' is now unchecked by default.

Also the line to remove the billing address on the billing step is not working. So now this is displayed on both places.

**EDIT:**

We also tried to use the Tigren method (https://www.tigren.com/billing-under-shipping-address-m2/) or the SR module (https://github.com/sohelrana09/modified-checkout). But these both have the same problem, the prefix is changed into an input field, instead of a select field. So it does not match the options from the backend anymore.

Image of the prefix input field (should be a select with values from backend):

[image]

Any idea how to solve this issue?

My LayoutProcessorPlugin.php code;

```
<?php

namespace Redable\ReorderBillingForm\Model\Checkout;

class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    )
    {
        // get billing address form at billing step
        $billingAddressForm = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form'];

        // move address form to shipping step
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['billing-address-form'] = $billingAddressForm;

        // remove form from billing step
        unset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['billing-address-form']);

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm asking this as I've seen a lot of posts where people write layout changes in PHP like this (the core does it sometimes to), it's exactly what layout XML is for so what is the advantage of writing it in PHP?

Comment: @BenCrook It's not possible to change this using the layout XML file, because the billing address can not be moved by changing the layout XML. That's why everybody is using PHP changes for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that looks like something you can do with XML but I'll take your word for it as nothing in Magento surprised me :P

Comment: @BenCrook, Would it hurt you to post answer using XML !! I would love to follow standards :)

Comment: so you want to move billing address from payment to below shipping address in shipping step. right?

Comment: @anonymous - It would definitely hurt me mentally, I try to avoid touching Magento 2 unless I have to.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel Yes indeed, that's correct.

Comment: @JGeer I will update you.

Comment: @JGeer could you pls post the screenshot of what you exactly would like to achieve. Becoz, two of the modules gives much flexibility but do not know what is missing that you need to show. It will be clear for the community.

Comment: @MageSoftech Thanks! See my update with the requested image. This prefix field is by default in the checkout a select element, with the values from the backend. But with these modules enabled, the prefix field in the billing address form is displayed as an input element.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve the issue for [Sohel's module](https://github.com/sohelrana09/modified-checkout) with below changes

Go to file **app/code/SR/ModifiedCheckout/Plugin/Block/LayoutProcessor.php** and update as per below.

Update your constructor as below.

```
public function __construct(
    AttributeMetadataDataProvider $attributeMetadataDataProvider,
    AttributeMapper $attributeMapper,
    AttributeMerger $merger,
    CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Options $options = null
) {
    $this->attributeMetadataDataProvider = $attributeMetadataDataProvider;
    $this->attributeMapper = $attributeMapper;
    $this->merger = $merger;
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->options = $options ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get(\Magento\Customer\Model\Options::class);
}
```

Now update your `aroundProcess` function with below code.

```
public function aroundProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    \Closure $proceed,
    array $jsLayout
) {

    $jsLayoutResult = $proceed($jsLayout);

    if($this->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
        return $jsLayoutResult;
    }

    $attributesToConvert = [
        'prefix' => [$this->options, 'getNamePrefixOptions'],
        'suffix' => [$this->options, 'getNameSuffixOptions'],
    ];

    if(isset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset'])) {

        $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][0]['placeholder'] = __('Street Address');
        $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['street']['children'][1]['placeholder'] = __('Street line 2');

        $elements = $this->getAddressAttributes();
        $elements = $this->convertElementsToSelect($elements, $attributesToConvert);
        $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['billing-address'] = $this->getCustomBillingAddressComponent($elements);

        $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['billing-address']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street']['children'][0]['placeholder'] = __('Street Address');
        $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['billing-address']['children']['form-fields']['children']['street']['children'][1]['placeholder'] = __('Street line 2');
    }

    if (isset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
        )) {
            foreach ($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                     ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {

                unset($jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]);

            }
        }

    return $jsLayoutResult;
}
```

Once you are done with above changes, add a new function `convertElementsToSelect` to convert prefix and suffix into a select dropdown.

```
private function convertElementsToSelect($elements, $attributesToConvert)
{
    $codes = array_keys($attributesToConvert);
    foreach (array_keys($elements) as $code) {
        if (!in_array($code, $codes)) {
            continue;
        }
        // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
        $options = call_user_func($attributesToConvert[$code]);
        if (!is_array($options)) {
            continue;
        }
        $elements[$code]['dataType'] = 'select';
        $elements[$code]['formElement'] = 'select';

        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            $elements[$code]['options'][] = [
                'value' => $key,
                'label' => $value,
            ];
        }
    }

    return $elements;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work almost perfect, but in fact we want to change the select field into a radio button. This is quite easy by changing the code into `$elements[$code]['dataType'] = 'checkbox-set'; $elements[$code]['formElement'] = 'checkbox-set';` The only problem we have is that we want to check the first value by default. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: And it also seems that the SR module does not remove the Billing Address checkbox on the payment step. So now there are two checkboxes in the checkout for the billing address.

Comment: Sure, @JGeer, I will check with above details. Would you please let me know if you are using default Magento checkout or any third party plugin for checkout page?

Comment: @JGeer, Please check updated `aroundProcess` method, I have added code to remove billing addresses from payment section. I will check if there is any way to select radio button by default.

Comment: Thanks again! Seems that we also needed to change the default M2 setting "Display Billing Address On" in the backend to "Payment Method" instead of below. Otherwise it still shows the billing address. Also any idea how to translate the Address: Line 1 phrase?

Comment: @JGeer, can you provide detail on which phrase you want to change to which one?

Comment: I want to change the phrase: `Street Address: Line 1`. The Street Address part is no problem, but I want to remove the `Line 1` part. I can not find a way to remove this.

Comment: I am checking it with default Magento setup but am not able to get "Line 1" text as described by you. Can you show me your screenshot for the same?

Comment: It seems that the SR module does not save the values in the DB. So the alternative billing address is not saved when it changed and it loads the shipping address that is entered. Can you help me out to implement your modification for the prefix into the Tigren module? The Tigren module is working fine for everything else and saves the value into the DB.

Comment: If you want to check the first value by default then add
`$elements[$code]['value'] = '0';` in that `convertElementsToSelect` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this below extension given here in my blog:

https://marketplace.magento.com/ananta-module-improvedcheckout.html

Tested and worked with 2.4.5

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below URL.
hope it useful for you.

https://www.tigren.com/billing-under-shipping-address-m2/

if you still need to change just let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried this, but that creates a entire new module and form. I only want to move the default form, instead of creating a new module and form.

Comment: Okay, I can Understand thanks

Comment: Thanks again! The only problem we have with this that the prefix does not work, it is displayed as an input field instead of a select box. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi many developers want to perform this : , You can take a help from this open source code available over github : 
https://github.com/sohelrana09/modified-checkout

I hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks! The only problem we have with this that the prefix does not work, it is displayed as an input field instead of a select box. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Js for that!

```
map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default":"Magento_ShippingChange/js/shipping-save-processor"
        }
    }
```

Then overwrite the address like this

```
define([
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
    'mage/storage',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
], function (
    ko,
    quote,
    resourceUrlManager,
    storage,
    paymentService,
    methodConverter,
    errorProcessor,
    fullScreenLoader,
    selectBillingAddressAction,
    createShippingAddress,
    selectShippingAddress,
    checkoutData,
) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        saveShippingInformation: function () {
            var payload,
                addressData,
                newShippingAddress;
            //Use this step if you want to change only field
            quote.billingAddress().firstname = quote.shippingAddress().firstname;
            //Use  this step if you want to replace whole address.
            quote.billingAddress()= quote.shippingAddress();

                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        'shipping_address': quote.shippingAddress(),
                        'billing_address': quote.billingAddress(),
                        'shipping_method_code': quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        'shipping_carrier_code': quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes: {

                        }
                    }
                };
            }else{
                if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                    selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
                }

                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        'shipping_address': quote.shippingAddress(),
                        'billing_address': quote.billingAddress(),
                        'shipping_method_code': quote.shippingMethod()['method_code'],
                        'shipping_carrier_code': quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code'],
                        extension_attributes: {

                        }
                    }
                };
            }

            fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

            return storage.post(
                resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                JSON.stringify(payload)
            ).done(
                function (response) {
                    quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                    paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                }
            ).fail(
                function (response) {
                    errorProcessor.process(response);
                    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                }
            );
        }
    };
}
```

);